# Using RestServiceAdapter in ADF Mobile 11.1.2.4.0

Tags: oracle-adf

After migrating to ADF Mobile 11.1.2.4 , the RestServiceAdapter library cannot connect to URL, or load the page that calls URL.

```
RestServiceAdapter restServiceAdapter = Model.createRestServiceAdapter();
restServiceAdapter.clearRequestProperties();
restServiceAdapter.setConnectionName("twitter");
restServiceAdapter.setRequestType(RestServiceAdapter.REQUEST_TYPE_GET);

restServiceAdapter.setRetryLimit(0);
restServiceAdapter.setRequestURI("/search.json?q=OC_WIRE");
String response = "";
try {
    response = restServiceAdapter.send("");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error...");
}
```

This code works fine in ADF Mobile 11.1.2.3.
Thanks for the replies

Comment: Try to hit the URL directly using HTTP Analyzer. If its isn't successful there, then it may be an issue with your proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since ADF 11.1.2.3 is using Phonegap and the latest is using Cordova, i think the best way to recreate the project back in ADF 11.1.2.4